# How to visualize an event timeline in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, temporal

I want to visualize the timestamps of events in my data using a visualization as shown below:

[image]

I guess this can be done in several different ways and with my lack of experience with D3, I'd like to hear a recommendation for a good approach. Perhaps it can achieved by manipulating some common visualization in an intricate way?

**EDIT:** Based on feedback from ee2Dev, I will do 4 lines instead of 2, capturing incoming and outgoing calls/texts separately. Regarding granularity, it would be best if the visualization could capture one week of data in 5 minute intervals (one text message will equal to 5 min of talking and a 48 minute call will be rounded up to a 50 minute call). That will amount to 7*24*12 = 2016 possible intervals, which seems somewhat reasonable. Perhaps 10 min intervals would be more suitable than 5 min intervals, but I guess the code can be easily adjusted for that. Something that I haven't shown is how midnight should be marked to show which days are active, and which are not.

Below is my code and my sample data:

```
// Data:
timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm),type
1/1/2015 10:12,inc_call
1/2/2015 10:12,inc_call
1/2/2015 10:12,out_text
1/3/2015 10:12,out_call
1/4/2015 10:12,inc_text
1/5/2015 10:12,inc_text


// Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="papaparse.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<link href="tipsy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>

var width = 1000;
var height = 500;

var events;

var results = Papa.parse("events.csv", {
    header: true,
    download: true, // is needed even for local files as this interprets the input value as a path instead of simply the data
    dynamicTyping: true,
    delimiter: ",",
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        events = results.data;  
        CreateVisualizationFromData();
      }
});


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var total_interactions;

function CreateVisualizationFromData()
{

    total_interactions = events.length;
    console.log(total_interactions);

    svg
      .append("marker")
      .attr("id", "arrowhead")
      .attr("refX", 6 + 7)
      .attr("refY", 2)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 4)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z");


 }
```

Comment: First of all: the choice of the visualization doesn't seem to be a good one: incoming and outcoming calls or texts are drawn in the same sequence, First I suggest you separate them out having four sequences. How should the algorithm choose to draw if there are a lot of incoming and outgoing call on one day. Fill half the region with light blue and the second half with dark blue ? Interleave light with dark blue ? Second make sure to show the viewer what time is depicted: I don't see where 1/1/2015 ends or where 1/5/2015 starts ? Is there 2nd - 4th in between or are we showing just 2 days ?

Comment: You might choose 4 separate graphs since it's really more suitable. An alterantive is also using four calendarView visualizations http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318 and instead of filling the whole day with one color, make the daily square 24x24 and draw 1 verticalline for each hour, if the hour discretization is enough granular

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree completely. The end result should instead be 4 lines. The data will show consecutive days so it would be the 1st to 5th. I've been thinking of how to illustrate the changes in days (e.g. with a think black lines when crossing midnight), but I'm still brainstorming on how to make it fit into the overall visualization. I'll update the original text accordingly.

Comment: what time granularity you want to depict ? call yes/no per hour ? per 30 minutes ?

Comment: See updated text. Do you think 5 min intervals across a week is too ambitious?

Comment: Well you can that, but if you use just 1 pixel width per interval you have a total width of 2016px + let's 30px for labels!

Comment: Hehe, true. I guess I wasn't thinking. It would just be interesting to somehow see whether the person was active with a 48 min call or just a call lasting 2 min.. Perhaps another option would be to do 1-hour intervals and then color-code that interval depending on the activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a starting point use this code and go from there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var colorOf = d3.scale.category10();

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], 0.3);

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([5, width]);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %Hh"));;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").parse;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("timeseries.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }));
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
  colorOf.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.type); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
      .attr("width", 1)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colorOf(d.type); })
});

function type(d) {
  d.time = parseDate(d.time);
  return d;
}

</script>
```

and here the file timeseries.csv

```
time,type
1/1/2015 10:12,inc_call
1/2/2015 10:12,inc_call
1/2/2015 10:12,out_text
1/3/2015 10:12,out_call
1/4/2015 10:12,inc_text
1/5/2015 10:12,inc_text
```

And here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/6u0a0qnw/
You might want to remove the y axis, replace it with labels, format the x axis...adjust the colors, etc..

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good starting point :) Could you very briefly go into more detail on what these 3 lines of code does?

`d3.csv("timeseries.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }));
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
  colorOf.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }));`

Comment: Some lines before that, I define three variables: colorOf, x and y. Each of the variables are pointing to a function, in particular, a scale function. Scales are functions that map from an input domain to a output range. The range of each scale has been set above - so in these three lines I set the correct domain.

Comment: So the first lines sets the domain to be an array of different types from your data (['inc_call', 'out_text', 'out_call', 'inc_text']. These values you want to map to different y coordinates. The second line assigns the min and max of time to be the domain for x. The last one maps all types to colors. Note that y and colorOf have the same domain (array of different types) but different ranges (y coordinates or colors)

Comment: you might look into the documentation of d3 scales , then you can easily adjust it.